# Merging two data sets by using common variables without listing all common variables in R

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have very large two data sets. And those have several common variables and different variables.

For instance, df1 and df2 have common variables a,b,c,d,e,f, and df1 has g,h,i and df2 has j,k,l for different variables.

I hope to have merged data set having a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l without listing all common variables like this `merge(df1,df2,by=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"),all.x=T,all.y=F)`

Is there a way of merging data sets without listing all common variables such as `by=c("a","b","c","d","e","f")` ??

Answer (score 1):

Use `left_join` function of `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1,df2)
```